# Query and modify advanced information about interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, netlink

I need to do following tasks:

- List the interfaces
- Set/remove/list IPv6 address
- Add/remove routing entries

AFAIK I cannot use `ioctl` I need to use netlink. The problem is that I couldn't find good description how to use it (most netlink tutorials concentrate on how to create connection). `strace` also didn't prove useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you look at the sources of iproute2. It has all the functionality you describe and uses netlink.

Comment: Hmm. I've tried it once and I hoped there is some documentation or description. It seems that I have no choice.